# How to add Client validation on view component property based on another value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am new to .net core development. I am building a form with one check box and one view component. I am using view component to have popup control in my form. That popup should have a value only when the checkbox is checked.
I am unable to provide this in client validation.
I am using jquery unobtrusive validators for client validation.
Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check that your checkbox is true , you should check with :

```
var checked = $('#myCheckBox').attr('checked');
if(checked){
alert("checked");
}
else{
alert("not checked");
}


<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
```